# Environment Variable replacement in Logstash when running as a service in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, logstash, logstash-configuration

I understand that logstash now supports environment variables in config, as described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/environment-variables.html).

But I can't seem to get it working when running logstash as a service.  I am on ubuntu 14.04, logstash 1:2.3.3-1, and I launch logstash with `sudo service logstash start`.

A final twist is that I am including logstash in a docker container, and I do NOT want to hardcode the variable value in my Dockerfile, I want it to ultimately be sourced from the command line when I launch the container, e.g. `docker run -e ES_HOST='my_host' ...etc...`.  This is really the main reason I want to use environment variables.

However the value does not seem to be making it all the way to logstash:

```
#<LogStash::ConfigurationError: Host '${ES_HOST}:443' was specified, but is not valid! Use either a full URL or a hostname:port string!>
```

Even taking the docker out of the mix, I cannot seem to get logstash to see the enviroment vars when I run it as a service.  I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44370/how-to-make-unix-service-see-environment-variables) about making environment variables available to services in ubuntu, so I added this line to the end of `/etc/default/logstash`:

```
ES_HOST=my_host
```

And I even inserted this into the /etc/init.d/logstash to make sure it was getting set:

```
[ -f /etc/default/logstash ] && . /etc/default/logstash
if [ -z "$ES_HOST" ] ;  then
  echo "ES_HOST is not set, please set it in /etc/default/logstash" >&2
  exit 1
fi
```

But logstash still gives the same error, complaining that `Host '${ES_HOST}:443' was specified, but is not valid!`

FYI the output section from my logstash config in `/etc/logstash/conf.d/my-config` looks like this:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["${ES_HOST}:443"]
    ssl => true
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, on a lark I tried moving the `:443` to the variable value.  Same basic result:  `Host '${ES_HOST}' was specified, but is not valid!`

Comment: Apparently the variable replacement works, but it's your host (:443) that's not valid for logstash. Perhaps logstash expects sthg like localhost:443

Comment: @baudsp Thx but as I said above, I tried `ES_HOST="my_host:443"` and using `hosts => ["${ES_HOST}"]` but it still doesn't work.  And if I just hardcode `hosts => ["my_host:443"]` into the config it works fine.  So the variable replacement does seem to me to be the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. And I can't help you any further :(