# Filebeat not replacing environment variable on windows when started as a service

Tags: windows, filebeat

I'm trying to have a filebeat running on a Windows 10 machine.

In my configuration I have some environment variables like:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: log
  enable: true
  paths:
    - '${My_Env_Variable}\logs\data.log*'
```

Everything works fine when I start filebeat through the command line with: `filebeat.exe -e -v`. But when I start as a service with: `Start-Service filebeat`
I have the following error in my logs:

> 2018-07-16T16:57:19.545+0200  ERROR   instance/beat.go:691    Exiting: Error in initing input: missing field accessing 'filebeat.inputs.0.paths.0' (source:'C:\Program Files\Filebeat\filebeat.yml')

I tried with single, double or no quotes at all.

It might be a possible duplicate of this question : [Environment Variable replacement in Logstash when running as a service in Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38064309/environment-variable-replacement-in-logstash-when-running-as-a-service-in-ubuntu)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When filebeat is started as a service, the user is root, so make sure your environment variables are system-wide